# in django set default image to ImageField as Default object

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model in the model and Imagefield is there.

```
class Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=" jobOpeningImages", default=' jobOpeningImages/1_oKH7Co9.jpeg', blank=True)
```

But I am not getting any current image URL in the localhost.
[image]

I am expecting this type of result

[image]

So how can we achieve the below? in first image

*Currently: jobOpeningImages/1_oKH7Co9.jpeg*

Comment: If you leave it blank, it will normally use the default one...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry! I didn't get you clearly.